# Debian Jessie FULL download

Tags: debian

I'd like to be able to download an ISO with **all** the .debs in it for amd64. The concept of CD and DVD is a bit behind the times when a 64GB USB stick costs $10 and plugs into any modern machine.

Does such a download exist? Can I use jigdo to do this? The instructions at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianCustomCD seem to be awfully complicated (perhaps geared towards the outdated CD mechanism).

It would be absolutely perfect if it was possible to create a USB disk that had a second partition, which can be used as a standard external hard drive. There should still be plenty of room left over.

Comment: If you really must download everything, consider mirroring a distribution tree. But consider how quickly the wealth of software you've downloaded will become out of date, and how little of it you will actually install. At this point it becomes more sensible to opt for Internet-based updates, even if they are obtained indirectly

Comment: I want a USB install to meet modern technology, not [four DVDs](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/8.1.0/amd64/iso-dvd/), which comes to 16GB .... well below the 64GB that my USB drive holds. This is Debian stable, so the packages will not be outdated except for security updates.

Comment: @drewbenn your point is taken, but I still want a FULL single Debian install image. I don't always have access to a network during the install --- e.g. offline machines (or, more accurately, machines that will be online after a lengthy network security activation process).

Comment: Then use `apt-cacher-ng` as suggested by @drewbenn. Would you like it as a formal "answer"? I'm sure drewbenn would oblige.

Comment: @roaima no, because it's not an answer to my question!